# What does this regex or preg_match check

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm not that familiar with regex. Can someone tell me what this regex is trying to do? Does it return boolean or an array?

```
$res = preg_match('#^[A-Z]{1}( [0-9]{1,3})?((\.[0-9]{1,3}){0,2})?$#i', $value);
```

Answer (score 4):

A breakdown...

- `^[A-Z]{1}` - from the beginning of the line, match one char from A-Z ... `[A-Z]`
- `( [0-9]{1,3})?` - subgroup \1 - match one space, then a number `[0-9]` 1-3 digits long `{1,3}`, `?` make this one optional.
- `((\.[0-9]{1,3}){0,2})?$` - subgroup \3 (nested in \2) - match literal `.` then a number `[0-9]` 1-3 digits long `{1,3}`, match 0-2 `{0,2}` of this previous group, and optional due to `?`, the `$` specifies that this match is done at the end of the line.
- `i` - end regex, set ignore case.  Which means, for example the first `[A-Z]` could be `[a-z]` without any change to the matches.

A few possible samples:

```
B 472.983.421     ( \1 = " 472" \2 = ".983.421" )

A                 ( \1 = "" \2 = "" )

C 18.1.1          ( \1 = " 18" \2 = ".1.1" )

D 0.0.0           ( \1 = " 0" \2 = ".0.0" )

d 0.0.0           ( \1 = " 0" \2 = ".0.0" ) # works due to the #i option.
```

And so on.

Comment: So it's trying to match an ip address or something?

Comment: IP would not need the leading `[A-Z]` and would need to match `{4}` of the `[0-9]{1,3}` groups, it just looks like an arbitrary serial or reference number. Note if it was doing an IP search you'd limit the [0-9]'s so that you matched 0-255 not 0-999, to avoid false positives.

Comment: +1. And, since nobody else mentioned it: the `{1}` in `[A-Z]{1}` does nothing but take up space.

Comment: @Alan, yup, I'd imagine the original author did that for clarity, but it's redundant.

Answer (score 1):

- Searches at the beginning of string for one character from A-Z: ^[A-Z]{1}
- space followed by 1-3 digit, might not be included (? at the end): ( [0-9]{1,3})?
- followed by a dot and 1-3 digit (repeated 0-2 times), might not be included: ((.[0-9]{1,3}){0,2})?

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match` always returns an int (1 if matched, 0 otherwise). If you want an array, it accepts a thrid parameter by reference that will be populated with the results.

Answer (score 1):

#                      start of match string

^                      starts with

[A-Z]{1}               starts with one uppercase letter

( [0-9]{1,3})?         possibly followed by a space and 3 digits

((.[0-9]{1,3}){0,2})? possibly followed by a pattern of dot then 1-3 digits zero, one or two times

$                      ends with (ie nothing after previous search critera

#                      end of match string

i                      case insensitive search